# Existence of a bijective function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> There exists a bijective function that when expressed as a subset of the Cartesian product has exactly 10,000 elements.

I think to the solution is: let $A=\{1,2,3,...,10000\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4,...,10001\}$ then if i  define $f:A \rightarrow B$ like $f(n)=n+1$ is clear than $f$ is a bijection and $|f|=10,000$ but im not sure.
Every suggestion or hint i will very grateful.

Comment: Seems fine. Any bijection between sets of cardinality $10000$ should work. The identity function on $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10000\}$ would also work, for example.